# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to ....CrExcessMaster

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

My code is

```
private List find(String queryString) {
    final Query query = getSession().createQuery(queryString.intern());
    List resultSet = query.list();
    return resultSet;
}
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public List < CrExcessMaster > getExcessesWidget(String primaryCO) {
    List cifList = find("select cem.id.cifNumber from CrEntitymaster cem where cem.primaryCo='" + primaryCO + "'");
    List < CrExcessMaster > temp = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < cifList.size(); i++) {
        log.info("cifList in dao " + cifList);
        if (i == 0) {
            temp = find("from CrExcessMaster where cif='" + cifList.get(i) + "'");
        } else temp.add((CrExcessMaster) find("from CrExcessMaster where cif='" + cifList.get(i) + "'"));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

where crExcessMaster is a table and I need to display variable temp value...
But when i try to call above returned value as below

```
public static FilteredUIExcessList formatCustomerExcessUiBean(List < CrExcessMaster > crExcessMasterList) {
if (crExcessMasterList != null) {
    FilteredUIExcessList filteredUIExcessList = new FilteredUIExcessList(); 
    < font color = red >
    for (CrExcessMaster crExcessMaster: crExcessMasterList) < /font>{
         ExcessUIBean excessUIBean = new ExcessUIBean();
         excessUIBean.setCurrency(crExcessMaster.getCurrency());
}
```

At the code highlighted in red, it is throwing classcast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to cib.ecm.creditRisk.excessManagement.db.orm.CrExcessMaster
```

Full Stack trace is

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to cib.ecm.creditRisk.excessManagement.db.orm.CrExcessMaster
    at cib.ecm.creditRisk.excessManagement.web.uiFormatters.UIBeanFormatter.formatCustomerExcessUiBean(UIBeanFormatter.java:65)
    at cib.ecm.creditRisk.excessManagement.web.services.ExcessManagementUiService.getExcessesWidget(ExcessManagementUiService.java:52)
    at cib.ecm.creditRisk.excessManagement.web.action.ExcessListActionBean.getExcessesWidget(ExcessListActionBean.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$6.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:442)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.invokeEventHandler(DispatcherHelper.java:440)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.invokeEventHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:285)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.doPost(DispatcherServlet.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.doGet(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:246)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at cib.ecm.creditRisk.excessManagement.web.filter.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `List` of `CrExcessMaster `to `formatCustomerExcessUiBean()` ?

Comment: And why did you suppress potential warnings ?

Comment: yeah...i printed the values and it is of crexcessmaster list type

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
} else temp.add((CrExcessMaster) find("from CrExcessMaster where cif='" + cifList.get(i) + "'"));
```

With this, you are adding a `List` to `temp`, wich is causing the `ClassCastException` later on. Instead of `temp.add()`, call `temp.addAll()`.